# Django Haystack - Stored/Indexed Fields - rendered hit database, and is there other method that not hit db in SearchQuerySet?

Tags: python, django, lucene, elasticsearch, django-haystack

### Problem

I try Stored/Indexed Fields(https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/searchindex_api.html?highlight=load_all%20=%20FALSE#stored-indexed-fields)

In Example,It dosen't hit django db, but my exam hit db.

#### Example Result

```
(0.002) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" IN (1); args=(1,)
[23/Oct/2013 08:19:01] "GET /search/?q=shin HTTP/1.1" 200 634
```

## Question

1. Misunderstanding? Wrong code?
2. And, I work with tastypie for instant search. So, is there function or option like rendered that not hit db in SearchQuerySet? (http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#adding-search-functionality)

### search.html

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}

    {{ result.rendered|safe }}

{% endfor %}
```

### user_rendered.txt

```
<h2>{{ object.username }}</h2>
```

### search_indexes.py

```
class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    username = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='username')
    email = indexes.CharField(model_attr='email')
    # Define the additional field.
    rendered = indexes.CharField(use_template=True, indexed=False)

    def get_model(self):
        return User

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Please, help me!